# How to get an input as either a letter or an integer?

Tags: c, input, calculator

I'm trying to make a scientific calculator. I have several different operations and the user needs to input a character to indicate which operator to use.

The list of operations in this simple calculator are:

sine (S), cosine (N), tangent (T), exponent (E) 
power (W), absolute (A), factorial (F) 
add (+), subtract (-), divide(/), multiply(*), modulus (%) 
Quit (Q)

So, for example, the application would look like this:

Enter user input: 30
Enter user input: S
Sin(30) = 0.5

I need to take input from the user, and allow them to enter an integer or a letter. How can I do this. Can I get an integer and a letter at the same time?

Comment: You want to use the [`istream& std::operator>>(istream&, T)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) function to do this.

Comment: [SO] is not a code writing service. You appear to be learning programming, so 1. Decide on C or C++ (these days they are very different languages). 2. Get yourself a tutorial (online, book, …) on that language and *work* through it. 3. Implement the beginnings. 4. Ask here when you have *specific* questions.

Comment: im  writing on c .and im not want a direct code i need an advice like you can research this subject etc.

Comment: @Akın For c lookup [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: in scanf() what type of variable should i take

Comment: @Akın , A string(`%s`). Then parse the string accordingly using a function like `sscanf`

Comment: @Akin you should input a string. And then try to parse it as an integer. If that fails parse it as a char. Depending whether you use c or c++ there are different parse functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use `scanf` with `%s` or `fgets`.

1. Get the input using `fgets`:

   ```
   fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
   ```

   Note that `fgets` includes the `\n` character in `buffer`. You may have to remove it.
2. Parse `buffer` using functions such as `sscanf`. This function returns the number of items successfully extracted from the buffer:

   ```
   if(sscanf(buffer,"%d",&num)==1) //Try to extract a number
       //Extraction successful!
   ```

   Otherwise , check if the first character of `buffer`(`buffer[0]`) is a valid character. Checks can be done to test the length of `buffer` too.

Answer (score 0):

you should validate the user input while taking input, you can do this by verifying ASCII value of input. one way would be to take input in form of string and then parse it for tokens.

Comment: Should i take string for characters and numbers ?after that return a ASCII numbers

Comment: int main()
{
char str[]="sa12";

int res = 0;
for (int i=0; i <4; i++) {
    char c = str[i];
    if (c < '0' || c > '9') 
    continue;
    
    res = res * 10 + (c - '0');}
    printf("%d",res);
} but java would be great to make these kind of applications

Comment: @user3013807: tip 1, please *do not post code in comments* (more so when it's a long swathe as this); tip 2: you can [edit] your own question and insert it right there.

Answer (score 0):

You may tame `strtol`: it has output parameter endptr, which will be set to the end-of-line if it successfully parsed integer. The rest of code is already explained by @CoolGuy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXINPUTLEN     32

int main() {
    char input[MAXINPUTLEN];
    char* eol;
    char* end;
    long l1;

    do {
        fputs("Enter user input: ", stdout);

        if(fgets(input, MAXINPUTLEN, stdin) == NULL)
            break;

        /* User entered empty string, exit the loop */
        if(input[0] == '\n')
            break;

        eol = strchr(input, '\n');
        if(eol == NULL) {
            /* Input string is too long, warn user, ignore the rest, and retry */
            fputs("Input is too long and may be truncated, please retry!\n", stderr);
            while(fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
            continue;
        }

        /* Remove newline character (should be the last) */
        *eol = '\0';

        l1 = strtol(input, &end, 10);
        if(end == eol) {
            /* User entered integer */
            printf("You have entered an integer: %ld\n", l1);
        }
        else {
            /* User entered a string */
            printf("You have entered a string: %s\n", input);
        }

        /* Read input unless user do not input an empty string */
    } while(input[0] != '\n');  
}
```